# Suspension bike

Tags: fork, suspension, bso

I recently bought a hyper plush 24 inch bike that says it has full suspension but only my rear suspension works I've seen other bikes for example an ozone 500 ultra shock it looks the same but mine is blue I've seen other people say they tried oil and other stuff it's OK if my front fork doesn't work but I just want to know

Comment: Not a dupe but relevant  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47129/my-bike-suspension-is-very-stiff-how-can-i-make-it-looser

Answer (score 3):

Presumably this is your bike - it clearly has front suspension.  If that doesn't work then you're either not heavy enough, or its faulty, or it is just cosmetic.

Apply the front brake while standing beside the bike.  Press down on the handlebars with all your bodyweight.  You should see the rubber zig-zag boots compress some.

If not, the bike is set up for a much heavier rider or the suspension isn't really there under the boots.

[image]

From https://www.argos.co.uk/product/8395298